# Lua elseif not working properly

Tags: if-statement, lua

When I attempt to use `elseif`, it doesn't work. In the case of the code below, no matter which number the user inputs, the only code that runs is the code under the if statement.

```
io.write("do you want to convert from celsius to farenheit (1), or the other way around (2)?")
pref = io.read()
if pref == 1 then
  io.write("Hi there! what's your temperature in celsius? ")
  local cel = io.read()
  far = (cel*1.8+32)
  io.write("That temperature in farenheit is: " .. far)
elseif pref == 2 then
  io.write("Hi there! what's your temperature in farenheit? ")
  local far = io.read()
  cel = ((far-32)/1.8)
  print("That temperature in celsius is: " .. cel)
end
```

Comment: A debugger/IDE would help see what code is being executed and the type and value of Lua values. [ZeroBrane, Eclipse, others](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaIntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments).

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with the `elseif`. The problem is because `io.read()` returns a string. Either convert it to a number:

```
pref = tonumber(io.read())
```

Or, compare `pref` with `"1"`, `"2"` instead.