# lua function argument treated as string?

Tags: lua

I am trying to make this program to factor a number work in lua, and everything works except for this one line of code in it. Here's the code:

```
function factor(a)
 print("factoring: " .. a)
 print()
 totali = 0
 totaldiv = 0
 for i = 1, a do
  if (a%i == 0) then
   if (i<a) then
    totaldiv = totaldiv + 1
   end
   print(i)
   i = i + 1
   totali = totali + 1
  else
   i = i + 1
  end
 end
 if totali == 2 then
  print("That is a prime number!")
 elseif totaldiv == a then
  print("That is a perfect number!")
 end
end
io.write("Enter a number to factor: ")
some = io.read()
factor(some)
io.read()
```

The offensive line is `if (i<a) then` from what I've seen.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The value you get back from `io.read` will be a string, yes. You need to convert it to a number if you want that (lua will do that implicitly in some cases too).

Comment: @Etan Reisner, How do I make the number the variable a? If it was, wouldn't it output 6 as a perfect number, or am I wrong in another part of it? It seems to me it's not making a the actual function argument. I did "i<tonumber(a)" EDIT: I changed it to totaldiv = totaldiv + i, but still no luck.

Comment: I have no idea what problem you are actually having. Your post was cut off and you didn't say what the problem was. I just gave a generic answer about `io.read` and string values. Fix your post, clearly explain the exact problem and I might be able to help more.

Comment: Ok... It cut off my post for some reason. I'm trying to get my program to output "That is a perfect number!" If the sum of its proper divisors is equal to the number itself. From what I'm seeing, it's not even doing anything with that part. I tried printing totaldiv after the for loop right before the second to last end, and it doesn't even print anything... I suck at this. OK I converted the last a to a number and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: If you have a solution you should write it up as an answer and accept it. You should also fix the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua elseif not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224290/lua-elseif-not-working-properly)

Comment: Replace `factor(some)` with `factor(some + 0)` or `factor(tonumber(some))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (i<tonumber(a)) then` should work.
You requested an input, which will be returned as a string.
Therefore, you can't do `if (i<a) then`, because you're comparing number and string via `<`.
You simply can't say, that 2 is less than '4'

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I was probably tired, when writing this. It's fixed now!