# Trying to receive a value from a user and increment it

Tags: lua, do-while

i'm new in progamming and starting with few basics tips. So my problem is:  i'm trying to run a code that ask user a name and print it on screen, its run ok. So i'm trying to do something special now  adding to code a part that ask the user  how many times the name will be printed on screen, but when i do that it start a infinite loop and won't stop until i close the progam.

Here its the code

```
function metodoDois()
  print("Write a name: ")
  name = io.read();
  print("Write how many times that it will be printed on screen: ")
  quantidade = io.read()

  k = 0;
  while name do
    k = k+1;
    io.write("\n", name, " ", k)
    if k == quantidade then
      name = not name;
    end
  end
end

metodoDois()
```

Comment: `io.read` returns a string. You need to use `tonumber` to convert it to a number for comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua elseif not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224290/lua-elseif-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to repeat a computation a *known* number of times, it is used a `for` loop. So, if you do not have specific reasons to use a `while` loop, you could go with:

```
function metodoDois()
   print("Write a name:")
   local name = io.read()
   print("Write how many times that it will be printed on screen:")
   local quantidade = io.read()

   for k = 1, quantidade do
      io.write("\n", name, " ", k)
   end

end

metodoDois()
```

This way, you avoid explicitly creating the control variable `k` and to perform a test at each iteration in order to asses when to end it. In fact, the control variable `k` in the `for`-loopis automatically updated at each iteration, letting the loop end when such variable gets its final value.
Moreover, `k` is *local* to the `for`-loop (i.e., it doesn't exist before or after it), making the code more readable and less error prone (see: [Local Variables and Blocks](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) in the Lua Reference.)

Comment: That's right. I would only keep `k` for the control variable to better show what is what in question and answer. And perhaps the same output.

Comment: Thanks, I spent two hours trying to solve this problem and now with your help could get it to work
Also this it worked in my way with some help above of the others with converting to a number but your way its simpler and i could learn something more ^.^
thanks again!

Comment: @PierPaolo Simply, I would follow the OP's naming and output, so I would use `k` instead of `I` in your example, and I would use `io.write("\n", name, " ", k)` instead of `io.write(name .. "\n")`. Just to show that the `k` variable is required anyway, and that the program behaviour is preserved after such changes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your "quantidade" variable is being read as a string, while your "k" variable is a number. Numbers and strings are not alike, so, for example, `1` isn't the same as `"1"`.

To fix this, simply convert the reading stored in the "quantidade" variable to a number first using the `tonumber()` function, by changing `quantidade = io.read()` to `quantidade = tonumber(io.read())` like so:

```
function metodoDois()
    print("Write a name: ")
    name = io.read();
    print("Write how many times that it will be printed on screen: ")
    quantidade = tonumber(io.read())
    k = 0;

    while name do
        k = k+1;
        io.write("\n", name, " ", k)
        if k == quantidade then
            name = not name;
        end
    end
end

metodoDois()
```

Also, this is just a nitpick, but that code seems a bit un-optimized! I'd recommend using something more like this:

```
function metodoDois()
    print("Write a name: ")
    local name = io.read();
    print("Write how many times that it will be printed on screen: ")
    local quantidade = tonumber(io.read())

    for k = 1, quantidade do
        io.write(name.." "..k.."\n")
    end
end

metodoDois()
```

Comment: Thanks man, i'm edited my progam to user select the two examples that u gived me, the first one to don't ask user how many time it will be printed, and the second one ask and use your example for more optmized!